# Seconds not Hiding on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

I'm working on creating a counter on my page, and so far I've got it to work alright... I've used this bit of CSS to hide the seconds portion, however when the page loads, it's shown briefly before it is hidden again.

Does anyone know how I can clear that brief showing part?

I've attached a video for your reference.
[Video Link](https://drive.google.com/a/onyxisland.com/file/d/1vKBnPpek9417Kx5i4G9SjTGNCDUank2J/view?usp=drivesdk)

The CSS snippet is also below, along with the JS part for the flipclock.

### CSS

```
.flip-clock-divider.seconds, 
.flip-clock-label,
.flip-clock-divider.seconds ~
.flip.play {
    display: none;
}

.header .clock{
  width: 100%;
}
```

### JS

```
clock = $(".clock").FlipClock({
    clockFace: "HourlyCounter",
    countdown: true,
    showSeconds: false,
    callbacks: {
      stop: function() {
        $(".message").html("The clock has stopped!");
      }
    }
  });
  clock.setTime(Math.floor(110945));
  clock.start();
```

Comment: https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock/issues/114    u can see this

Answer (score 0):

hey change clockFace and u can remove that css

```
clockFace: 'DailyCounter',
showSeconds: false
```